# Creating pairs of objects in a list

Tags: python

I have a list of objects:

```
object_list = ['distance', 'alpha1', 'alpha2', 'gamma']
```

I want to obtain a new list with a pair combination of those objects, such as:

```
new_list = [ ['distance', 'alpha1'], ['distance', 'alpha2'], ['distance', 'gamma'],['alpha1', 'alpha2'], [ 'alpha1', 'gamma'] ... ]
```

Generally I will obtain 24 sublists(cases).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python code to pick out all possible combinations from a list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/python-code-to-pick-out-all-possible-combinations-from-a-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) - [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) seems to be the thing you are looking for. use like

```
import itertools
object_list = ['distance', 'alpha1', 'alpha2', 'gamma']
new_list = list(itertools.combinations(object_list, 2))
```

Comment: I try to extend my task and use lists instead of strings.

    distance = ['3', '-3']
    alpha1 = ['3', '-3']
    alpha2 = ['3', '-3']
    gamma = ['3', '-3']
    Is there easy way to use lists instead of strings?

Comment: just set `object_list = [ ['3', '-3'], ['3', '-3'], ['3', '-3'],  ['3', '-3']]`

Answer (score 1):

[itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) if order isn't important or [itertools.permutations](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) if order matters

### itertools.combinations

```
>>> a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> list(itertools.combinations(a, 2))
('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'c')]   # Order isn't important
```

### itertools.permutations

```
>>> a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> list(itertools.permutations(a, 2))
[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'a'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'a'), ('c', 'b')]  #Order matters
```